# Pass HashTable to View from Controller in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there  a way to pass a `HashTable` loaded with key/values to a page View in a way I can then use it via javascript/Jquery ?

**Example:** I have HashTable with

```
key = Car Model (206 XT), Value = "PEUGEOT", etc...............
```

So in the view I have a combo with all car models and near that, I have a textbox automatically populated with the manufacturer taken from javascript

Is there a way to do so ??

(I'm really noob in MVC 3 :()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different way to solve this problem:

if you wan't to get this list dynamicaly with out reloading you can use a json request ([examples](http://blog.js-development.com/2011/08/posting-json-data-to-aspnet-mvc-3-web.html)).

**Javascript:**

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/controler/action",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: jsonData,
       success: function (result){

         for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        var value = result[i];
        alert(i =") "+value);
    }
       }
```

**Controler (c#):**

```
  [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult Action()
   {
      return Json(YourTable.ToArray()); 
   }
```

Furthermore you can access every html-element from javascript. So you can put the content in all kinds of html-elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize most C# objects using the following method in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hashtable = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.YourHashtable)
</script>
```

If you have some Tree like data structures with parent/child relationships you might run into issues as the Encoder can't solve circular relationships.